# Select from explicit cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Is there a way to select from an explicit cursor without having to use a loop with `IF` conditions to filter the cursor?

In other words, if I have the following cursor...

```sql
CURSOR cur_emp IS
  SELECT * FROM emp;
```

is there a way to do the following?

```sql
DECLARE
  v_row cur_emp%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO v_row FROM cur_emp WHERE id_emp < 10;
  /* Do something */
END;
```

Comment: Alas, no. Ref Cursors are a PL/SQL construct and static SQL can't handle them. I agree it would be a highly neat extension to the SQL engine. It would certainly have made my life easier over the years..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No but change the cursor instead

```
CURSOR cur_emp(iEmpid in emp.id_emp%TYPE) IS
  SELECT * FROM emp
   WHERE id_emp < iEmpid;
```

and

```
for rEmp in cur_emp(10) loop
  -- do something
end loop;
```

OR

Skip the cursor and put the hole thing into the for loop, its just as effective.

```
for rEmp in (SELECT * FROM emp WHERE id_emp < 10) loop
  -- do something
end loop;
```